# What happens when sliding a stick over and over on a closed loop

Tags: geometry, limits

There is a closed continuous loop, and you have a stick of a random fixed positive length,so that You can slide the stick on the loop. Take the stick's midpoint. It's track will form another closed continuous loop. Take another stick of another random fixed positive length. Slide it on the new loop again. It's midpoint will form another loop. Do this again and again. Will the shape of the loops tend towards a circle(well, the area of the loop may decrease, but you can magnify the area to not let it become a point)? Or could it become another shape?

The thing I found was that circles and ellipses will tend towards a circle, and I think the question is intuitive, because this operation of sliding sticks round's spikes and makes concave shapes convex.